# dropdown selected value change event in vtiger crm

Tags: vtiger

I have two `Dropdown` one is city and one for state so i want that when the user select city  `Dropdown` the state will be select from the `Dropdown` . Also i want that when user select the second `Dropdown` that is state some `Textbox` and label will he hide from the form .

I read the example from the link but not understand how i can create formula for this.
[Vtiger Formula](https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Field_Formulas)

So how can i do this in vtiger crm

Answer (score 1):

Create One file and name it what you want with .php extention. And Paste this code in body format.

```
<select name="cat_sub_type_name" id="cat_sub_type_name" class="small">
<?php
require_once('include/utils/utils.php'); //new
require_once('include/utils/RecurringType.php');
require_once 'include/QueryGenerator/QueryGenerator.php';
require_once 'include/ListView/ListViewController.php';
$q=$_GET['q'];
include 'config.inc.php';
$s="select * from cat_sub_type where cat_type = '$q'";
$res = $adb->pquery($s, array());
$num_rows = $adb->num_rows($res);
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) 
{
$name = $adb->query_result($res, $i, "cat_sub_type_name");
echo "<option value='$name'>".$name."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Add this ajax code on the module.js file and also in .tpl file in which you have added the fields.

```
function getCombo1($fieldname,$tablename)
{
$id = vtlib_purify($_REQUEST['record']);
global $adb, $mod_strings,$current_user;
require('user_privileges/user_privileges_'.$current_user->id.'.php');
$combo = '';
$combo .= '<select name="'.$fieldname.'" id="'.$fieldname.'" class=small>';
$q = 'select * from vtiger_activity WHERE activityid =?';
$Res = $adb->pquery($q,array($id));
$noofrows = $adb->num_rows($Res);
for($i = 0; $i < $noofrows; $i++)
{
     $value = $adb->query_result($Res,$i,$fieldname);
     $combo .= '<option value="'.$value.'">'.getTranslatedString($value).'</option>';
}
$combo .= '</select>';
return $combo;
```

}

Now just give the onchange event on first dropdown like this

```
 <select name="{$fldname}" tabindex="{$vt_tab}" class="small" style="width:160px;" onchange="showuser(this.value)">
```

I hope this hepls you.